# Cloning Heroku postgresql DB to local db for "live" testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

So I've followed all of the guides I can find online for this issue, including similar stack posts, but things are not working.

I ran the command

`heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`

and got

`postgres://<username>:<password>@<host_name>:<port>/<dbname>`

(with all of the <> parts being my DB info of course) and ran

`pg_dump --host=<host_name> --port=<port> --username=<username> --password <dbname> > output.sql`

At this point I needed to run

`psql -d <local_database_name> -f output.sql`

but my rails app followed the Michael Hartl tutorial which uses sqlite3, so I had to switch things over. I tried this by changing my database.yml file to

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
# adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development
# database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test
# database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production
# database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I also changed the Gemfile to use 'pg' instead of 'sqlite3' in development. At this point I  ran `bundle install` and tried `rails db:setup` and `rails db:migrate` which did not create the databases (.. uh oh) and when I run the final step of

`psql -d db/development -f db/output.sql`

I get plenty of console output, but when I run a rails console sandbox, there is no user info from my Heroku database. Did I miss a step? What's going on? (I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04)

**Edit**:

First, I undid all of the local changes I made above. Then, I ended up following a combo of the above and the guide here http://manuelvanrijn.nl/blog/2012/01/18/convert-postgresql-to-sqlite/. I used `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL` to get all of the needed host, port, username, etc. info and then pulled the data with

```
pg_dump --host=<host_name> --port=<port> --username=<username> --password --data-only --inserts <dbname> > dump.sql
```

After that I followed the postgresql to sqlite database conversion (the "Longer story a.k.a please explain a little more." version) I linked above. I did all of the edits described in step 2 as well as having to remove a bunch of `SELECT` statements at the end of `dump.sql`. Another change I had to make was replacing all `INSERT INTO` instances with `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` to satisfy some unique constraint errors in step 4. That did it!

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export Have you had a look at this guide? This is the method I use and it sounds like it would work for your setup.

Comment: I have not, I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks for the lead

Comment: @Arvoreniad, that did not end up working out for me, but I reverted all the changes I made in my post and followed the guide here http://manuelvanrijn.nl/blog/2012/01/18/convert-postgresql-to-sqlite/ with some slight modifications and got things to work. I will post an edit with how I got things to work for any future traveler later. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: no problem, glad you got it working in the end